# Scala Salat deserialization error with @key

Tags: scala, casbah, salat

I have a case class that looks like this:

```
import com.novus.salat.annotations.raw.Key
import org.bson.types.ObjectId

case class Users(
                  _id: ObjectId,
                  email: String,
                  password: String,
                  firstName: String,
                  lastName: String,
                  company: Option[String],
                  position: Option[String],
                  enabled: Boolean)
```

And a simple SalatDAO:

```
import com.novus.salat.dao.SalatDAO
import org.bson.types.ObjectId
import com.novus.salat.global._

object UsersDAO extends SalatDAO[Users, ObjectId](
  collection = MongoFactory.getCollection("usersCollection"))
```

So now I want to change "_id" to "id". I thought that Salat @Key annotation is indeed for that purpose. So I write:

```
...
@Key("_id") id: ObjectId,
...
```

And when I try `UsersDAO.find(MongoDBObject.empty)` I get an exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com...Users$.apply$default$1()
```

What interesting - if I do the same thing but for another class where "id: String" I get this exception

```
java.lang.Exception: class com...AnotherClass requires value for 'id'
```

Can anyone throw sunshine on that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to fix your import.  Use

```
import com.novus.salat.annotations._
```

to properly target the `@Key` annotation to the `getter`.

See https://github.com/salat/salat/wiki/Annotations

Comment: Thanks! Works fine now.
Actually @EnumAs worked fine with just
{
    import com.novus.salat.EnumStrategy
    import com.novus.salat.annotations.EnumAs
}

Comment: Sorry, I know, it's not consistent.  I should get rid of the `@getter` targeting requirements for the rest of the annotations, it's been a pain to support.